# Imagemagick: Mask mutliple images using black-and-white mask

Tags: image-processing, imagemagick, mask, image-manipulation, imagemagick-convert

I have a series of black-and-white images, like this:

[image: Source image]

ImageMagick converts thems to mask, using `connected-components`

```
magick *.png -define connected-components:area-threshold=130 -define connected-components:mean-color=true -connected-components 8 -negate mask\mask-%02d.png
```

[image: Mask]

After that I'd like to apply this masks to original images and get images without grid lines.

How to do this using one ImageMagick command? I have the series of images, not one.

Comment: I showed you how to do that at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75899269/imagemagick-how-to-remove-grid-lines-and-dark-regions-from-an-image/75903162?noredirect=1#comment133889178_75903162. Why are you asking this question multiple time?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Imagemagick: How to remove grid lines and dark regions from an image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75899269/imagemagick-how-to-remove-grid-lines-and-dark-regions-from-an-image)

Comment: No, because I ask about images masking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way might be to composite the two images together choosing the darker of the two at each pixel location:

```
magick aaeDd.png Sf07q.png -compose darken -composite result.jpg
```

[image]

---

If you want to do all steps in a single command, you can use:

```
magick aaeDd.png \
  \(                                                 \
     +clone                                          \
     -define connected-components:area-threshold=130 \
     -define connected-components:mean-color=true    \
     -connected-components 8 -negate                 \
  \) -compose darken -composite result.jpg
```

Comment: Nice. But how to join this comman with previous one? Son I need to construct a mask and compose it with source image in one command. Also there are series of images.

Comment: Please refrain from using `magick convert ...` it is nearly always wrong! https://stackoverflow.com/a/61208844/2836621

Comment: If you have lots of images to process, use **GNU Parallel** like I suggested on your previous question. Or use Python multiprocessing.

Comment: So, you could say that `magick *.png ...` does not work for a series of images?

Comment: Correct, exactly as Fred (@fmw42) told you in his comment here https://stackoverflow.com/q/75897397/2836621

Comment: In Windows-batch `+clone` doesn't work. Instead of it I use the following `magick infile.png -write mpr:img ^( mpr:image ... -write mpr:mask ) mpr:img mpr:mask -compose darken -composite otfile.png`

Comment: If it is the `+`sign upsetting Windows, you can more simply replace it with `-clone 0`.

Comment: I try `-clone 0` but it does not work too.